# How to add a 1 into a list based on the values of another list, which give the position of where 1 should go

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:

```
a = [1,4,5]
x = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

I am stuck on making it so that it could look like this:

```
x= [0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]
```

So that the number 1 is added to list x based on the value of list a, where the list values in a determine the position of where 1 should go. I am not sure if that makes much sense but it would help a lot.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a for loop to iterate through list `a` and set the indexes of list `x` of its values to 1. So for example:

```py
a = [1, 4, 5]
x = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

for index in a: # Iterating through the list a
    x[index] = 1 # Setting the values to 1 

print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative way,
using numpy fast and efficient

```
np_x = np.array(x)
np_x[a]=1
```

Comment: back to list -> list(np_x), If you plan to do many calculations on your list then using numpy is a very good choice from my point of view